# Duplicate Output error when exporting Access query to SharePoint list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a number of tables in Access, linked in from SQL Server. From these I've created a simple query that I am trying to export to SharePoint following [this guide](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Export-a-table-or-query-to-a-SharePoint-site-10d03c99-08f6-43ca-b210-7535097d0de6).

When I run the export I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

I've assumed the export is conflicting with the enforced Title column in SharePoint lists. The query originally had a column called Title, so I first tried renaming it with an alias. This didn't work so now I've removed that column from the query entirely but I'm still getting this error.

Google hasn't helped, I've managed to find someone with the same issue, but they removed the title column and that worked for them.

What is causing this, and what can be done to fix it, or work around it?

**Using**
Access 2013 and SharePoint 2010 with a SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Answer (score 1):

So I've solved it:

Access sneds up the tables used in the query, including columns not used in the query.

Because one of the tables had a column called Table it created a conflict.